# Copy files to another geolocation tenant using a Flow

Tags: power-automate

Need to automate the copying of files when added or modified in a Sharepoint organizational assets library over to a different tenant org assets site - so from domain.sharepoint.com/sites/orgassets/library to domaingbr.sharepoint.com/sites/orgassets/library. The "copy file" action doesn't work for this and and throws an error: *Copy or move can't rename or replace an existing item at the specified destination location.*
That suggests the Flow can't connect to the destination site, but I'm an admin on both sites and the connection is working right. I've tried every other suggestion I could find with no luck.

Comment: Are you using the `Copy file` action, and if so at the bottom, what have you see for the `If another file is already there` option?

Comment: I selected "replace" there but discovered you have to use a different connection for the destination sites so copy file won't work. I used createfile instead so I could add a different connection.